# Access n-th element after string splitting

Tags: r, string, split, apply

I have a string that looks like:

```
string <- c("A,1,some text,200", "B,2,some other text,300", "A,3,yet another one,100")
```

So every vector element is further divided by commas.
Now I only want to extract elements at a certain place. Let's say all the elements before the first comma or all the elements after the second comma.

The following code does what I want:

```
sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x){return(x[[1]])})
# [1] "A" "B" "A"
sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x){return(x[[3]])})
# [1] "some text" "some other text" "yet another one"
```

However this code seems fairly complicated to me (given the simplicity of the question). Are there more concise options to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1) data.frame** Convert to a data frame and then it is easy to pick off a column or subset of columns:

```
DF <- read.table(text = string, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)

DF[[1]]
## [1] "A" "B" "A"

DF[[3]]
## [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"

DF[-1]
##   V2              V3  V4
## 1  1       some text 200
## 2  2 some other text 300
## 3  3 yet another one 100

DF[2:3]
##   V2              V3
## 1  1       some text
## 2  2 some other text
## 3  3 yet another one
```

**2) data.table::tranpose**  The data.table package has a function to tranpose lists so that if `stringt` is the tranposed list then `stringt[[3]]` is the vector of third fields, say, in a similar way to (1).  Even more compact is data.table's `tstrsplit` mentioned by @Henrik below or the same package's `fread` mentioned by @akrun below.

```
library(data.table)

stringt <- transpose(strsplit(string, ","))

# or
stringt <- tstrsplit(string, ",")

stringt[[1]]
## [1] "A" "B" "A"

stringt[[3]]
## [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"

stringt[-1]
## [[1]]
## [1] "1" "2" "3"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
##
## [[3]]
## [1] "200" "300" "100"

stringt[2:3]
## [[1]]
## [1] "1" "2" "3"
##
## [[2]]
## [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

purrr also has a `transpose` function but

```
library(purrr)
transpose(strsplit(string, ","))
```

produces a list of lists rather than a list of character vectors.

Comment: Instead of `transpose(strsplit`, you may use the convenience function `tstrsplit`

Comment: Good idea. Have incorporated.

Comment: You could use `fread` as well `fread(paste(string, collapse="\n")`

Comment: Is there a reason, not to use base R? See my suggestion below.

Comment: @Christoph. (1) does use base R only.

Comment: Accepted this answer because of the first part using a `data.frame`. This solution most naturally reduced my problem to another (well known) problem: subsetting a 2-dimensional data structure. This approach (because of the shift to `data.frame`) simplified also much of the computations done later in my code.

Answer (score 6):

One option is to use `word` from `stringr` with `sep` argument

```
library(stringr)
word(string, 1, sep = ",")
#[1] "A" "B" "A"

word(string, 3, sep = ",")
#[1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

---

Since the performance of `word` is the worst among all I found out another option using regular expression in base R.

```
#Get 1st element
sub("(?:[^,],){0}([^,]*).*", "\\1",string)
#[1] "A" "B" "A"

#Get 3rd element
sub("(?:[^,],){2}([^,]*).*", "\\1",string)
#[1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

There are two groups to match here. First one matches any characters that are not a comma followed by a comma for `n` times and then again matches another set of characters that are not comma. The first group is not captured (`?:`) while the second group is captured and returned. Also note that the number in brackets (`{}`) has to be one less than the word we want. So `{0}` returns 1st word and `{2}` returns 3rd word.

**Benchmark**

```
string <- c("A,1,some text,200","B,2,some other text,300","A,3,yet another one,100")
string <- rep(string, 1e5)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  tmfmnk_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x) x[1]),
  tmfmnk_tstrsplit = tstrsplit(string, ",")[[1]],
  avid_useR_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), '[', 1),
  avid_useR_str_split = str_split(string, ",", simplify = TRUE)[,1],
  Ronak_Shah_word = word(string, 1, sep = ","),
  Ronak_Shah_sub = sub("(?:[^,],){0}([^,]*).*", "\\1",string),
  G_Grothendieck ={DF <- read.table(text = string, sep = ",",as.is = TRUE);DF[[1]]},
  times = 5
)
#Unit: milliseconds
#               expr     min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
#      tmfmnk_sapply 1629.69 1641.61 2128.14 1834.99 1893.43 3640.96     5
#   tmfmnk_tstrsplit 1269.94 1283.79 1286.29 1286.68 1290.76 1300.30     5
#   avid_useR_sapply 1445.40 1447.64 1555.76 1498.14 1609.52 1778.13     5
#avid_useR_str_split  324.68  332.28  332.30  333.97  334.01  336.54     5
#    Ronak_Shah_word 6571.29 6810.92 6956.20 6930.86 7217.26 7250.69     5
#     Ronak_Shah_sub  349.76  354.77  356.91  358.91  359.17  361.94     5
#     G_Grothendieck  354.93  358.24  364.43  362.24  367.79  378.94     5
```

I haven't included Christoph's solution as it is not clear to me how it will work for variable `n`'s. For example for 3rd position , for 4th position etc.

Answer (score 5):

We can simplify OP's code to:

```
sapply(strsplit(string, ","), '[', 1)
# [1] "A" "B" "A"

sapply(strsplit(string, ","), '[', 3)
# [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

Also, with `stringr::str_split` and `simplify = TRUE`, we can directly index the column, since the output would be a matrix:

```
library(stringr)
str_split(string, ",", simplify = TRUE)[,1]
# [1] "A" "B" "A"

str_split(string, ",", simplify = TRUE)[,3]
# [1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

Answer (score 3):

A slight variation on the version with `sapply()`:

```
sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x) x[1])

[1] "A" "B" "A"

sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x) x[3])

[1] "some text"       "some other text" "yet another one"
```

Or a different possibility could be using `tstrsplit` from `data.table`:

```
tstrsplit(string, ",")[[1]]

[1] "A" "B" "A"
```

Benchmark of the different solutions:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
 tmfmnk_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x) x[1]),
 tmfmnk_tstrsplit = tstrsplit(string, ",")[[1]],
 avid_useR_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), '[', 1),
 avid_useR_str_split = str_split(string, ",", simplify = TRUE)[,1],
 Ronak_Shah = word(string, 1, sep = ","),
 times = 5
)

                expr     min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval cld
       tmfmnk_sapply  34.543  36.395  45.8782  47.150  48.540  62.763     5  a 
    tmfmnk_tstrsplit  33.072  33.554  39.1166  35.012  36.116  57.829     5  a 
    avid_useR_sapply  39.612  45.292  61.1936  46.730  47.398 126.936     5  a 
 avid_useR_str_split  27.313  34.095  49.3412  43.834  43.977  97.487     5  a 
          Ronak_Shah 146.875 147.277 199.4978 162.995 218.322 322.020     5   b
```

Benchmarks on the replicated "string":

```
string <- rep(string, 1e5)

microbenchmark(
 tmfmnk_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), function(x) x[1]),
 tmfmnk_tstrsplit = tstrsplit(string, ",")[[1]],
 avid_useR_sapply = sapply(strsplit(string, ","), '[', 1),
 avid_useR_str_split = str_split(string, ",", simplify = TRUE)[,1],
 Ronak_Shah = word(string, 1, sep = ","),
 Christoph = regmatches(string, regexpr("^[^,]", string)),
 times = 5
)

                expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
       tmfmnk_sapply 1529.8955 1608.2909 1926.7776 1820.0443 2105.9736 2569.6836     5
    tmfmnk_tstrsplit 1277.8712 1281.0371 1482.4520 1314.0074 1599.7686 1939.5757     5
    avid_useR_sapply 1428.7175 1470.9002 1487.5425 1483.1127 1521.3735 1533.6087     5
 avid_useR_str_split  306.2633  316.7539  360.8785  334.8516  335.5375  510.9863     5
          Ronak_Shah 5541.6199 5657.3593 5955.9653 6068.1067 6166.7249 6346.0157     5
           Christoph  231.0496  244.1049  383.9702  246.0421  273.2877  925.3667     5
```

Comment: Are you using the same `string` for benchmarking.   A bigger data benchmark gives more meaningful result

Comment: Interesting to see that `word` is so much slower than the rest.. I guess saving development time sometimes come at a cost of run time.

Comment: @avid_useR the results are indeed interesting.

Comment: 1) package solutions are usually slower. Just type in `word` in the console to see its source code and observe how many lines of code it has. 2) Which solution to use completely depends on the situation. For example on small sets (like the one shared by OP) you'll not "feel" any difference in execution time for any of the solution. All of them are almost instant.

Answer (score 2):

It can be done using base R using regepr:

```
regmatches(string, regexpr("^[^,]", string))
[1] "A" "B" "A"
regmatches(string, regexpr("[^,]*$", string))
[1] "200" "300" "100"
regmatches(string, regexpr("[^,]*,[^,]*$", string))
[1] "some text,200"       "some other text,300" "yet another one,100"
```